# How short can an RF transmission line be?

Tags: arduino, rf, antenna, transmission-line

Design for connecting transmitters to antennas often mentions the transmission line, and the standing wave ratio (SWR) for matching.  But what if the transmitter is on the antenna?

Background: I've an old 151 MHz narrow band FM 10mW transmit module TX1 from Radiometrix that I'd like to deploy monitoring a solar powered pump on a stock dam.

I plan to attach the RF out and RF ground pins on the module directly to either the base of a quarter wave with groundplane, or at the feed point of a yagi, or across a "slim jim" or J-pole antenna.

An Arduino Pro Mini will be adjacent to the transmit module, and a multi core cable will head down to the other equipment.

So the transmission line will be only a few millimetres long, and measurement of SWR seems impractical.

(This is a licensed use per [schedule 1 item 15](http://www.comlaw.gov.au/Details/F2013C00396), 150.7875 to 152.49375, max EIRP 100mW.  Source code, which details connections, is [here](http://dev.laptop.org/~quozl/z/1VHt0k.txt))

Comment: I suspect that there isn't any sort of robust lighting protection on the inputs. You should really think about adding some sort of lightning protection to this as well, as I suspect a close by lightning strike would leave this a smoking wreck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any connection shorter than λ/10 (1/10 of the electrical wavelength, or about 20 cm @ 150 MHz) cannot usefully be treated as a transmission line. In that case, you need to match the transmitter directly to the antennna (or vice-versa). If needed, you  can use discrete coils and capacitors to do that.

Comment: Thanks.  My next question would be: why and how does one match a transmitter directly to an antenna using discrete coils and capacitors?

Comment: You should pose it as a question then. Comment fields aren't appropriate for follow-up questions in the StackExchange metaverse.

Comment: For l < 0.1 x wavelength, you can still treat the wire as a transmission line. It will be lots of extra calculation work to get close to the same answer as if you ignore transmission-line effects. But you won't get a wrong answer.